# How to show a many-to-many relationship in drupal 7? Example: Teachers who guide a certain course

Tags: views, 8

I would like someone to guide me regarding relationships.

I have a many-to-many relationship (Course, Teacher) and I need to show the teachers that guide a certain course.
What module or way is recommended to do it?
How can I show it in a view or block?

(I have been testing the Relation module but I still can not do it)

Comment: The question might be misleading. Are you trying to connect many Courses and many Teachers in a single relationship? Usually one end of a Relationship is a single entity, while the other end could be more than one. For example one Course will have many Teachers associated. You can use Entity reference field on your Course to add Unlimited number of Teachers. Try reading more here: [Getting Started with the Entity Reference module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1327954), or a Tutorial: [Getting Started with References in Drupal](https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/getting-started-references-drupal).

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer !!
I am new with drupal, so there are things that I can not accomplish very easily the first time, however, I have already managed to solve my problem using the Entity Reference module and View Relatioships.

What I need is something like: A course has many teachers, and a teacher teaches in many courses.

I received that suggestion also in the facebook drupal support community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with the use of Entity Reference and View Relationships.
I have created an Entity reference type field in my content type, managed to relate it to another type of content.
Then, with the use of View Relationships and capturing the node id, I can show the types of content associated with a specific node.

Answer (score -1):

You can use entity module for relationships

Comment: Thank you!!
I have used Entity Reference and View Relationships